# Prove that $512^3 + 675^3 + 720^3$ is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried to use the fact, $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: FWIW, it factors into $229 \times 467 \times 7621$, but I assume you want an answer that doesn't rely on a computer.

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: Not all sums of three positive cubes are composite. For example, $3=1^3+1^3+1^3$ and $17=1^3+2^3+2^3$ are two primes that are the sum of three positive cubes.

Comment: @Starlight I got it from a book Excursion in Mathematics

Comment: @Dan, right, I need some kind of factorisation which doesn't involve computer

Comment: Please don't put clarifications and additional information into the comments. Instead, revise your post so that it incorporates all relevant information and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.   Please refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/14578 for advice on how to use this site effectively.